# PHP Image Upload Error

Tags: php

Here's my code within a form to upload a file....

```
            <tr>
            <td>File</td>
            <td><input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br></td>
        </tr>
```

And here's my php within the action page:

```
$allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$extension = end($temp);
if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/x-png")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png"))
&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 2000000)
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
  {
if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
{
echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
}
else
  {
    echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
   echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
   echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
     echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br>";

   if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
  {
  echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
  }
else
  {
  move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
  "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
  echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];

  }
}
 }
 else
   {
    echo "Invalid file";
  }
```

THe image seems to upload ok, but moving things around doesn't seem to be working. I get the following error...

```
Upload: bobscafe.png
Type: image/png
Size: 200.578125 kB
Temp file: /home/content/03/12112303/tmp/phpOR48Au
```

> Warning: move_uploaded_file(upload/bobscafe.png)
>   [function.move-uploaded-file]: failed to open stream: No such file or
>   directory in /home/content/03/12112303/html/kena/builder.php on line
>   38
>
> Warning: move_uploaded_file() [function.move-uploaded-file]: Unable to
>   move '/home/content/03/12112303/tmp/phpOR48Au' to
>   'upload/bobscafe.png' in
>   /home/content/03/12112303/html/kena/builder.php on line 38 Stored in:
>   upload/bobscafe.png98802424

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Give the full path , like: `/home/user/upload/`

Comment: destination directory exits and is writeable by the web server?

Comment: ... *plus,* your form does in fact contain `enctype="multipart/form-data"` ?

Answer (score 0):

Check the filesystem permissions. Probably your apache server cannot write in upload destination.

And specify the full destination path, for example :

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
                   __DIR__ . "/upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
```

Plus instead of / sign use DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR constant. They you will be able to use you code also on Windows servers :)